# Get error message from a Google Test after running it

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm implementing a custom runner for Google Testing Framework that runs a concrete `TestInfo` separately and checks its status:

```
TestInfo* info = ...;
testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = std::string(info->test_case_name()) + "." + info->name();
RUN_ALL_TESTS();
std::cout << (info->result()->Passed() ? "Success :)" : "Error :(") << std::endl;
```

Here `testInfo->result()` has type `TestResult`, which has methods that provide information on whether the test has passed or failed, was the failure critical, and also properties which can be set by user.

But google tests can also have a failure message, i. e. `FAIL() << "Division by zero";`.
Is there any way to retrieve this failure message from the Google Test api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downloaded GitHub repo of googletest and looked through code. Seems that your `FAIL()` message can be retrieved by next code (don't have any gtest project to test correctness of code):

```
for (auto const & pr:
      testing::internal::TestResultAccessor::test_part_results(*info->result()))
    if (pr.fatally_failed())
        std::cout << "FAIL(): " << pr.message() << std::endl;
```

Please, correct me if I'm wrong, I'll update my answer.

**UPDATE**. Just found less hacky way (without using `::internal`) after looking at code, also not tested:

```
for (int i = 0; i < info->result()->total_part_count(); ++i) {
    auto const & pr = info->result()->GetTestPartResult(i);
    if (pr.fatally_failed())
        std::cout << "FAIL(): " << pr.message() << std::endl;
}
```